# button press automaticly in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, driver

Gues, I meet smthing extremely weird. Shortly, I've a program that buy shoes automaticly from dif accounts on cite: https://brandshop.ru/new/. So, I need to login this cite I find fields email and password and send keys to em BUT smthing wrong with button when I trying to click submit button.

test.txt:

stackover@gmail.com:qazwsxedc

secondstackover@gmail.com:qazwsxedc

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

def login(email, password):

    url = 'https://brandshop.ru/new/'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver') # connecting driver

    driver.get(url)

    driver.find_element_by_class_name('user').click()  # class = 'user' 

    time.sleep(1.5) ##

    driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)  # from file

    time.sleep(2) ##

    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password) # from file

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Вход"]').click() #PROBLEM HERE

    time.sleep(8)

    driver.close()

accs = open('test.txt')

for i in range(0, 2):

    string = accs.readline()

    string = string.split(':')

    email = string[0]

    password = string[1]

    login(email, password)
```

If I comment driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Вход"]').click() for the first account button pushes **independently** and on the second account nothing happens.

If I uncomment driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Вход"]').click() for the first account button pushes and programm finishes with error:

```
   File "C:\PYTHON38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\PYTHON38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 

{"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()="Вход"]"}

  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `WebDriverWait`, try following code:

```
def login(email, password):
    driver.get('https://brandshop.ru/new/')
    driver.maximize_window()
    btn_user = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='nav-right']//div[last()]")))
    btn_user.click()

    txt_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email")))
    txt_email.send_keys(email)

    txt_password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password")))
    txt_password.send_keys(password)

    btn_login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='nav-right']//button")))
    btn_login.click()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I tried 
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.user .btn.btn-aqua.btn-fluid"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)

Comment: @Hush Code updated with full login function, I've added `WebDriverWait`, please try again.

Comment: I tried:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55842/devtools/browser/3fc1b072-b4e6-4176-b5ac-ad425ef6f2d5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    login(email, password)
  File "test.py", line 23, in login
    btn_login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='nav-right']//button")))
  File "C:\PYTHON38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: